# Setting height 100% on display:table won't work if a 'flex' row has too many items (only firefox)

Tags: html, css

I have a table with height 100% and three rows, the first and last ones have a fixed height, and the one in the middle has no specific height so it stretches to the necessary height.

The problem is that if you fill that row with too many items, the table will be too big and it will exceeds the 100%.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="first" class="row">
    <div>
    first
    </div>
</div>

<div id="second" class="row">
  <div>


    <div style="height:50px">
    cont0
    </div>
    <div style="height:50px">
    cont1
    </div>
    <div style="height:50px">
    cont2
    </div>
    <div style="height:50px">
    cont3
    </div>
    <div style="height:50px">
    cont4
    </div>
    <div style="height:50px">
    cont5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="first" class="row">
     <div>
    last
    </div>
</div>
```

```
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}

#wrapper{
   width:300px;
   height:100%;
   display:table;
}
.row 
{
   display:table-row;
}

#first
{
   height:50px;
   margin-bottom:5px;
   background-color:#F5DEB3;    
}

#second{
   background-color:#9ACD32;
}
#second > div{
  height:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

It's difficult to explain, but this fiddle demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/3EjX8/127/

Resize the table with your mouse in chrome and it will behave nice (scrollbar appears inside the table).
But resize it in firefox and it will have this unexpected behavior.

Maybe I'm wrong and I'm taking good part of a chrome's bug.

I'm just wondering if there is a possibility to make this behave in firefox as it does on chrome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work on both firefox, chrome.

1. Don't use display: table for this, not necessary
2. You had the id "first" two times.
3. You don't need divs inside divs
4. Use 'calc' it's a life saver.

http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/p3rcyofk/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first" class="row">

        first

    </div>

    <div id="second" class="row">
      <div>


        <div style="height:50px">
        cont0
        </div>
        <div style="height:50px">
        cont1
        </div>
        <div style="height:50px">
        cont2
        </div>
        <div style="height:50px">
        cont3
        </div>
        <div style="height:50px">
        cont4
        </div>
        <div style="height:50px">
        cont5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="last" class="row">

        last

    </div>
</div>


html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
#wrapper
{
   width:300px;
   height:100%;
}


#first,#last
{
   height:50px;
   background-color:#F5DEB3;

}

#second{
   background-color:#9ACD32;
}
#second {
  height:calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this won't solve my problem since, eventually, more rows (with fixed px height) are going to appear (i'm sorry because i didn't say this in my first post), but for this reason I think that I can't use calc in this situation, can I?

Comment: it can still solve it. for example let's say you'd have 5 rows besides #second. then #second would be calc(100% - 5*50px); if you add rows dynamically then you'd need to do to do this via javascript for example, with each row that gets added you'd need to subtract 50px from #second. if you want a more robust solution use flexboxes (http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) but I find flexboxes a bit more complicated to use. and flexbox will only work in the newest browsers.